# How many connections reads queue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker

Is there a way to get to know how many external tasks (console applications) is reading queue?

I am using Service Broker external activator.

What i want is something similar to information i get from [sys.dm_broker_activated_tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175029.aspx), just for external queue readers.

Comment: this belongs on dba

Comment: How would it know? There's no requirement that these external tasks maintain a connection to the server at all times, nor that they notify the server when they shut down, nor even that the process that is launched isn't just a bootstrap process that launches the *real* external task that reads from the queue.

Comment: just like internal activated procedures- if there is connection AND transaction that reads data from queue, then 1, else 0.. (and it is possible to see how many external tasks is waiting for message to arrive to queue) @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of. You can see though [`sys.dm_exec_requests`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx) executing a RECEIVE statement (including a WAITFOR RECEIVE). By simply peeking into the the currently executing text [`sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181929.aspx) between the `statement_start_offset` and `statement_end_offset` you can see if the statement is RECEIVE or not (with some parsing...). Figuring out if an active transaction has issued a RECEIVE and is now processing returned messages is more complicated.

Is somehow of an unusual request, why do you need to know?

Comment: Messages are processed in console app, it calls web services, sometimes it can slow down (it happens while receive transaction is open). Was thinking of the easy way to monitor what is happening.

Comment: [Instrument the console app](http://rusanu.com/2009/04/11/using-xslt-to-generate-performance-counters-code/), add application performance counters to trace duration and count of operations.